# Jquery infinite scroll doesn't call action method - probably routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, infinite-scroll

I use infinite scroll for paging. And it was working fine until today. Today I have decided to add two additional parameters to all my action methods and something is wrong now with pointing action method from infinite scroll.
So when I scroll the page action is not invoked.
So I open page source and find link that should load next page and it looks like:

```
href="/Tickets/AnotherSetOfData?countryCode=uk&cityName=london&ticketTypeId=-1"
```

If I click on this link action method is invoked, so the problem is that infinite scroll somehow stops to call this function on scroll.
This is how action method looks like

```
public ActionResult AnotherSetOfData(string countryCode, string cityName, int ticketTypeId)
{...}
```

I suspect that maybe this is routing issue but I don't know how to handle it...

**Routing**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

**Infinite scroll**

```
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a href="@Url.Action("AnotherSetOfData", "Tickets", new { countryCode = ViewBag.countryCode, cityName = ViewBag.cityName, ticketTypeId = ViewBag.ticketTypeId })">
    </a>
</nav>
...
$container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
            nextSelector: '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector: '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
        },

      function (newElements) {

          var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });

          $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {

              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              $container.isotope('appended', $newElems);
          });
```

Comment: have you set the routing up for this? lets see the routing code please :)

Comment: the infinite scroll setup would be also interesting to see...

Comment: I have updated question that is all what I have in routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
"InfiniScroll", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{countryCode}/{cityName}/{ticketTypeId}", //URL with parameters
new { controller = "Tickets", action = "AnotherSetOfData"}); // Parameter Defaults
```

Comment: Nothing happens if I add that route :(

Comment: Hmm, works for me.. I am not familiar with the Infinity scroll thing but I do not see where it is grabbing the results and loading them back in with ajax.. I just see you creating a link in a div.

Comment: Have you used FireBug / HTTPFox to debug this? To see if it is actually making the call but perhaps not loading the results? See if the jquery is firing as expected when expected?

Comment: Action from that link div is called when you scroll down. That action should be called and than returned data are loaded on page in 'function (newElements)...'. Problem is that there are no data because that link div is not invoked from some reason.

Comment: Stupid me (again) I forgot that to infinite scroll to work must have "id" parameter in method that it calls. So by using your a little modified route (added {id}) it worked.